# Magento usps shipping charges not showing in paypal order review

Tags: paypal, magento-1.9, usps

I am using usps in magento and its showing in onepage checkout page as well.
But the problem is usps shipping charges are not showing in paypal Your order summary.
I am using paypal express checkout and magento version 1.9.2.4

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: the question is more fit for Magento specific site: http://magento.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I posted it there.Thanks

Comment: Getting similar issue some time.